# Changing the alignment of a TextView using LayoutParams Not working

Tags: android, textview, alignment, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

I want to use this code to change the alignment of my textView in the layout programmatically.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)textView1.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
textView1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

But When I try it `RelativeLayout` doesn't have ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT or generaly Align_... what should I do?

Comment: Did you call `requestLayout` after `setLayoutParams`?

Comment: try textView1.setGravity(RIGHT);

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
params.AddRule (LayoutRules.AlignRight);
```

Instead of :

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
```

It works now...